# Groups: showing $ab=1$ implies $ba=1$. 

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $1$ is the identity in $G$. Suppose $a$,
$b$ in $G$ and $ab=1$, how could one simply show that $ba=1$?

Thanks!

Comment: Multiply $ab=1$ on the left by $a^{-1}$.

Comment: @Anonymous. Now can you prove this: if $z$ is an element of the center $Z(G)$ of $G$, and let $a, b$ in $G$ with $ab=z$. Then $ba=z$.

Answer (score 8):

By the [axioms for a group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28mathematics%29#Definition), there exists some element $c\in G$ such that
$$ac=ca=1.$$
Thus, if $ab=1$, then 
$$cab=c1=c$$
but also
$$cab=1b=b$$
hence $c=b$, and therefore $ac=ca=1$ implies that $ab=ba=1$. (Incidentally, this also shows that the inverse of an element in a group is unique.)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative proof which may or may not be easier:

Multiply $ab = 1$ on the left by $a^{-1}$ to yield:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
a^{-1}ab & = & a^{-1}1 \\
1b & = & a^{-1} \\
b & = & a^{-1}
\end{eqnarray}$$

Now multiply on the right by $a$ to obtain:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
ba & = & a^{-1}a \\
ba & = & 1
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: MathJax gets a little confused when you use `eqnarray` outside of mathmode. The two ways to fix the issue are: (i) enclose it in `$$`; then it works as usual. And (ii) use a "triple backslash", `\\\`, for the end-of-line; the first backslash informs the parser that the next characters should be treated literally, and that solves the issue as well. I used the former to fix it; then I rolled back your edit because the eqnarray displays are better than a sequence of displays.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I did not know that; thanks!